# CSR Request Keychain iOS Distribution certificate

Tags: ios, keychain, csr

I need to create a new distribution certificate. For that i am using the keychain tool to create a CSR request. I have to provide an e-mail and common name for that. Does this information has to match with my apple id or is that irrelevant?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not mandatory to match the email Id with your apple Id, instead you can provide any other email address also to identify with this certificate and the common name is used for the keychain to show the in the name list of the certificates.

This will create the CSR file which will contains the public private key pair